# Purpose of 'would' here

Tags: modal-verbs, modality, will-would

"I **would** definitely encourage each of you to follow-up on their initiative,write e-mails,posters,talk to professors and even reach out to people outside the university."

Is **would** used in above line as a hedge(just for softening) or do it has some purpose? Can 'will' be used in above line without change in sense?

Answer (score 1):

It is precisely a hedge.

Pragmatically, the speaker is, of course, encouraging the hearers to do what the sentence says; but it is avoiding actually saying they are doing so. If they used "will", or no modal at all, they would explicitly be encouraging (or saying that they were definitely going to be doing so) which is a much stronger and more direct statement.